# parsec: stopping at empty line

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I would like to solve the following task with parsec, although `splitOn "\n\n"` is probably the simpler answer.
I have an inputstring like

```hs
testInput = unlines ["ab", "cd", "", "e"] -- "ab\ncd\n\ne"
```

The parser shall stop when encountering an empty line.

I tried this

```hs
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

inputFileP :: GenParser Char st String
inputFileP = many (lower <|> delimP)

delimP :: GenParser Char st Char
delimP = do
  x <- char '\n'
  notFollowedBy (char '\n')
  return x
```

This fails with `unexpected '\n'`.
Why?
I was under the impression that `many x` parses `x` until it fails and then stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was under the impression that many x parses x until it fails and then stops.

This is only the case if `x` fails without consuming any input. If `x` fails after consuming input, the whole parse will fail unless there's a `try` somewhere (this isn't just specific to `many`: `x <|> y` would also fail in that case even if `y` would succeed). In your case `delimP` fails on the `notFollowedBy (char '\n')` after already consuming the first `\n`, so the whole parse fails.

To change this behaviour, you need to explicitly enable backtracking using `try` like this:

```
delimP = try $ do
  x <- char '\n'
  notFollowedBy (char '\n')
  return x
```

Alternatively, you can make it so that `delimP` fails without consuming any input (and thus no need for try) by making it look ahead by two characters *before* matching the `\n`:

```
delimP = do
  notFollowedBy (string "\n\n")
  char '\n'
```